# why do i have 2 versions of gcc and g++ in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, command-line-tool

I just had a fresh re-installation of **Mac OS X Yosemite** before I install **Xcode** and then **CommandlineTools**.

It seems I have two versions of gcc and g++ in the following two directories:

1. **/usr/bin** (both files are 14kb) and
2. **/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin** (g++ is just an alias and gcc is 19kb)

Type "which gcc" in the Terminal gives me "/usr/bin/gcc", so did "which g++" which gives me "/usr/bin/g++", and this means the system will only use the gcc and g++ in /usr/bin

So, my questions are:

**1. why do I have two versions of gcc and g++?**

**2. why the gcc and g++ installed with CommandLineTools is not specified as the default ones?**

**3. How do I ask the Mac OS X to point to the gcc and g++ in the directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin"?**

BTW, i installed CommandlineTools according to the following:

http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html

However, I got a different output by typing "gcc --version" (difference hightlighted):

Configured with: --prefix=**/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr** --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix

... rather than **/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr** as shown in the web page above ...

I'm quite confused about which gcc/g++ is actually being used by Mac OSX currently ...

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OSX doesn't use gcc (g++). It defaults to Clang since Mac OSX 10.7. So when you type gcc or g++  to compile it actually uses Clang (cc)

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you call 'cc' or 'cxx' or 'c++' you are calling clang. Read here for more information about the state of Apple clang (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CompilerTools/Conceptual/LLVMCompilerOverview/)

Adding to what @adnan-kamili said, you may wonder why Apple did that. So here is a short answer from Llia Lebedev (https://www.quora.com/Compilers-Why-did-Apple-create-Clang)

> A factor in their decision may certainly have been GCC's license. GPL
>   is highly restrictive when it comes to non-free software.
>   Specifically, GPL requires derivative projects to be provided with
>   their full and open source, also licensed under GPL.
>
> While a reasonable course of action available to Apple would be to
>   dedicate a handful of smart engineers to beef up GCC's support for
>   everything Apple, the license would require their work to be to be
>   released under GPL as well - a tricky proposition within a large
>   corporation, as it would likely force significant amounts of Apple
>   software hooking into GCC to be released under GPL also.
>
> Clang was open-sourced under the much more permissive University of
>   Illinois License, which allows Apple to develop private branches of
>   Clang without releasing full source code.